# Copy structure member to an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
struct {
    char a[10];
    char b[5];
    char c[10];
} info;
```

How can I concatenate all the `struct` data members into one single array?

Comment: If you can ensure that there are no gaps between the struct members due to alignment, you can simply memcpy the struct as a whole.

Comment: Are the members "arrays of `char`" or are they "nul-terminated strings"?

Comment: @Chris: They are null terminated string!

Comment: An example of what you want based on some start values would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [`memcpy()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/):

```
// Assign a buffer big enough to hold everything
char *buf = malloc(sizeof(info.a) + sizeof(info.b) + sizeof(info.c));
// Get a pointer to the beginning of the buffer
char *p = buf;
// Copy sizeof(info.a) bytes of stuff from info.a to p
memcpy(p, info.a, sizeof(info.a));
// Advance p to point immediately after the copy of info.a
p += sizeof(info.a);
// And so on...
memcpy(p, info.b, sizeof(info.b));
p += sizeof(info.b);
memcpy(p, info.c, sizeof(info.c));
```

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner to C can you please xplain how the process actually works? Thank you

Comment: OP said (above) that the data fields are nul-terminated strings, so you need to use `strlen` and `strcpy` or `strcat`.

Comment: @Chris and @Oli: When I try to print the single buffer I only get a part of data! Do I have to put it in a loop to print the entire data?!

Comment: @Oli: Can I store the pointer data(*p or *buf) in to an array data[50]?!

Comment: can I concatenate all the struct data members into one single array without using a malloc?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to copy the struct array members into a single array without using a pointer? Because I am trying to pass a fixed length array into another function. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sprintf. This funcions 'prints' a string into anoter:

```
int struct_size = sizeof(info);
char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*struct_size);
sprintf(result, "%s%s%s", info.a, info.b, info.c);
```

Comment: Can I concatenate all the struct data members into one single array without using a malloc?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to copy the struct array members into a single array without using a pointer? Because I am trying to pass a fixed length array into another function. Thank you for your time and help.