# Copy values to and from a member of a structure in C++

Tags: c++, structure, memcpy

I have a structure as shown below, which I use for the purpose of sorting a vector while keeping track of the indices.

```
struct val_order{
        int order;
        double value;
};
```

(1). Currently what I do is use a loop to copy values as shown below. So my first question is if there is a faster way to copy values to a member of a structure (not copying an entire structure to another structure)

```
int n=x.size();
std::vector<val_order> index(n);
for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){        //<------So using a loop to copy values.
    index[i].value=x[i]; 
    index[i].order=i;
}
```

(2). My second question has to do with copying one member of a structure to an array. I found a [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221910/copy-structure-member-to-an-array) that discusses using `memcpy` to accomplish that. But I was unable to make it work (code below). The error message I got was `class std::vector<val_order, std::allocator<val_order> > has no member named ‘order’`. But I was able to access the values in index.order by iterating over it. So I wonder what is wrong with my code.

```
int *buf=malloc(sizeof(index[0].order)*n);
int *output=buf;
memcpy(output, index.order, sizeof(index.order));
```

Comment: What is `x`? (e.g. `x.size()`, `x[i]`)

Comment: For #2, use _index_ for `index` such as  `index[0].order` in `memcpy(...`.

Comment: @DyP: It's just a vector of values that I would like to copy to the value member of the structure. I have no problem doing the copying via looping.

Comment: @MM. You are referring to the second argument inside `memcpy()`, right?

Comment: @Alex: Second and third

Comment: What is the type of x?

Comment: @andre It's of the type double

Comment: `int n=x.size();` makes no sense then. double does not have a `size()` member.

Comment: @Alex if `x` is of type `double`, then how does `x.size()` compile?  You appear to be confused: `std::vector<double> x` is not of type `double`, it is of type `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Isn't `size()` supposed to tell me the number of items held in a vector? `x` is a `std::vector`

Comment: Alex, when asked "What is the type of x?", you said "it's of type double".  Now you are saying it is a `std::vector`.  You seem to be confused.

Comment: @Yakk: Uh, sorry, I meant it's a vector which holds data points of the type double ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question 1*

Since you are initializing your n vectors from two different sources (array *x* and variable *i*), it would be difficult to avoid a loop. (you could initialize the vectors from `index.assign` if you had an array of `val_order` already filled with values, see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/))

*Question 2*

You want to copy all n *order* values into a *int* array, and *memcpy* seems convenient for that. Unfortunately,

- each element of a vector is a `val_order` structure, so even though you could copy via *memcpy* that would not only copy the *int* *order* value but also the *double* *value* value
- furthermore, you are dealing with *vector*, which internal structure is not a simple array (*vector* allows operations that are not possible with a regular array) and thus you cannot copy a bunch of *vector* to a *int* array by simply giving the address of, say, the first vector element to *memcpy*.
- also, *memcpy* wouldn't work like you want anyway, but it expects an address - thus you would have to give, e.g., `&index[0]` ... but again, this is not what you want given the points above

So you would have to make another loop instead, like

```
int *buf = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
int *output = buf;
for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
   output[i] = index[i].order;
}
```

Comment: You can as well replace `malloc` with `new` or even another `std::vector`.

Comment: I will look into `std::assign`. Your sample code is similar to what I did - using loops works perfectly fine, but I was looking for ways to perhaps simplify the code and speed up things. Do you happen to know if `assign` offers any improvement in terms of speed compared to using a simple loop?

Another question: do I really need to initialize `output` like that? Can I not simply do `int output[n]` with `n` being the number of items held in the vector `x`.

Comment: @Alex *assign* should be faster as it perform the multiple assigns without the same index calculation and function calls - shouldn't make a big difference, especially when compiling with optimizations. Declaring `int output[n]` works - the difference is it will be local to the current function (while malloc needs a *free*, and its pointer could be used after the function returns (and before the *free*)).